# Rational Application Developer

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I downloaded Rational Application Developer 9.7 and Websphere Application Server Traditional 8.5.0.0.

When I went to Preferences, I still can't choose Compiler as Java 1.7. Any ideas?

I have proper JDK installed as well.

Comment: You mean you can't select "Compiler compliance level" of "1.7"?  Is the option simply not included in the drop-down or are you saying you selected it but it's not working somehow?   If you go to Java->Installed JREs what is the Java version of the JRE selected as the default?

Comment: First, When I go to Windows Prefrences under Java - Compiler. When I Select Java Compiler 1.7 from dropdown, it pops the message "When Selecting 1.7 Compliance make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activated(currently 1.6). But in IBM i already installed RAD 9.7.0, WebShphere App Server 8.5.5.0 and SDK Java Tech. Edition 7.0.2.0.

Comment: Can you go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and select the Java V7 as the default?

Comment: If I follow the path, it says "Conflicting compliance seetings can be changed on the Compiler Page". It also mentions "The selected JRE does not support compiler level of 1.7".

Comment: It's back and forth with the same message on tab Compiler and Installed JRE.

Comment: I think you might still need to go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs  and click "Add" and then reference the path of the Java 7 JRE/JDK on your system.